# How to pass string with whitespace as a parameter in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a function like this

```
 $.get("/Test/GetTest/" + form, function (data) {
                var items = "";

                $.each(data, function (i, t) {
                    items += "<div onclick =" + "GetBlah(' " + t.Text + "')" + ">" + t.Text + "</div>";
                });
...

function GetBlah(s) // if t.Text got whitespace it throws me error
{
  ...
}
```

How can I pass string with whitespace to function in jquery?

Comment: You are generating invalid HTML. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Jon Thank you for your reply. Is there any solution to pass string with whitespace?

Comment: @Lakhae -- you should pay more attention to the comment by Jon -- it was meant seriously and it will help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`<div onclick=GetBlah('Text with a space')></div`

Without double quotes wrapping the attribute value, the  value of the `onclick` attribute is `GetBlah('Text`.

HOwever, I would recommend instead using a `data-` attribute to hold the text and binding a click handler that pulls the value from there.

```
items += '<div class="text-div" data-text="' + t.Text + '">' + t.Text + '</div>';
```

---

```
$(document).on('click', '.text-div', function() {
    var text = $(this).data('text');
});
```

Either way, make sure the text doesn't have double quotes in the value, or be sure to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes around the attribute value, so only part of it is used when there is a space in it.

Also, to avoid problems with other characters, you would need to escape some characters in the string and HTML encode other.

The easiest way to handle those problems is not to create HTML code at all, but create elements directly:

```
var items = [];
$.each(data, function (i, t) {
  items.push($('<div>').text(t.Text).click(function(){ GetBlah(t.Text); }));
});
```

Now you can append the array of elements just as you would append the string with HTML code.